# Change username link in admin bar

Tags: php, links, buddypress

when i click on the username in the adminbar it redirect me to the edit profile page of buddypress. My question is,how can i change it to user activity page? thank you very much.

Comment: you can do that with the action `admin_bar_menu`. look the function `wp_admin_bar_my_account_menu`

Comment: @mmm can you leave that as an answer instead of a comment with an example? Comments are for clarifying questions not answers

Comment: thank you mmm but it's not clear. can you post the code that i have to insert in my function.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following directory and file.
`wp-content/mu-plugins/admin-bar-tweaks.php`
Or, you can add this to your theme's `functions.php` file.

- In the script below, remember to set `$new_url` to whatever you desire.

---

```
<?php // Requires PHP 5.4+.
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', function( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $new_url = 'http://example.com/custom/location';

    if ( $wp_admin_bar->get_node( 'my-account') ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( [
            'id'   => 'my-account',
            'href' => $new_url,
        ] );
    }
    if ( $wp_admin_bar->get_node( 'user-info') ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( [
            'id'   => 'user-info',
            'href' => $new_url,
        ] );
    }
    if ( $wp_admin_bar->get_node( 'edit-profile') ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( [
            'id'   => 'edit-profile',
            'href' => $new_url,
        ] );
    }
} );
```

A quick walk through this.

- Attach to the `admin_bar_menu` hook.
- Check if the `my-account`, `user-info`, and/or `edit-profile` nodes exist.
- If each/any of them do, add them back in again, this time with a new URL. *Note: When calling `WP_Admin_Bar::add_node()`, any properties you do not define will simply be set to whatever they were already. In this case, we are simply changing the `href` to `$new_url`.*

To learn more, see: [WP_Admin_Bar](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/)
See also: [WP_Admin_Bar::add_node()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/add_node/)
See also: [default nodes](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c9e84315821e0865def9d62e43377af6ca9d448e/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L109) in WordPress core.

Comment: Quite welcome. Given the above, you just need to find the BuddyPress nodes. See: https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/search?q=wp_admin_bar